# Laravel testing is it possible to have followingRedirects after the assertSessionHas

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am testing in laravel and saw yesterday that you can't have followingRedirects before assertSessionHas. So I wanted to know if it is possible to have it after the assertSessionHas without repeating the whole test code. I have now this a temporary solution:

```
$response = $this->post('/signup', [
        'username' => 'Testing',
        'email' => 'testing@test.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'password_confirmation' => 'secret',
    ]);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', ['username' => 'Testing', 'email' => 'testing@test.com']);
    $response->assertSessionHas('success', 'Your account has been created!');
    $code = $this->followRedirects($response)->getStatusCode();
    $this->assertEquals(200, $code);
```

But I want to know if you are able to change the response later on with the followingRedirects instead of using it this way.

Answer (score 1):

When sending a post request in Laravel using PHPUnit, you don't need to pass the `csrf_token()`, it is included automatically.

I would refactor your code like this:

```
$this->post('/signup', [
    'username' => 'Testing',
    'email' => 'testing@test.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'password_confirmation' => 'secret',
])->assertStatus(200)
->assertSessionHas('success', 'Your account has been created!');

$user = User::latest()->first();

$this->assertEquals('Testing', $user->name);
$this->assertEquals('testing@test.com', $user->email);
```

Comment: With this code I get the problem that the assertStatus is 302 because you don't redirect it anymore

Comment: This is just an example of how I would refractor what you wrote initially. Try removing `assertStatus` call & then check.